# cx_Oracle & Connecting to Oracle DB Remotely

Tags: cx-oracle

How do you connect to a remote server via IP address in the manner that TOAD, SqlDeveloper, are able to connect to databases with just the ip address, username, SID and password?

Whenever I try to specify and IP address, it seems to be taking it locally.

In other words, how should the string for cx_Oracle.connect() be formatted to a non local database?

There was a previous post which listed as an answer connecting to Oracle via cx_Oracle module with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cx_Oracle
connstr='scott/tiger'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute('select * from emp')
print curs.description
for row in curs:
    print row
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 61):

I like to do it this way:

```
ip = '192.168.0.1'
port = 1521
SID = 'YOURSIDHERE'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)

db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', dsn_tns)
```

One of the main reasons I like this method is that I usually have a TNSNAMES.ORA file lying around someplace, and I can check that the `dsn_tns` object will do the right thing by doing:

```
print dsn_tns
```

and comparing the output to my TNSNAMES.ORA

Comment: FYI - this doesn't work when connecting to 11g RAC that requires a service name rather than a SID. The connstr method works as a service name.

Comment: This works for me using `cx_Oracle-5.1.3-11g.win32-py2.7` and connecting to oracle 10g where as `user/pass@host:port/dbname` always fails. thank you.

Comment: You can find IP with this `SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual;` and SID with this     `SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 30):

You can specify the server in the connection string, e.g.:

```
import cx_Oracle
connstr = 'scott/tiger@server:1521/orcl'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
```

- "server" is the server, or the IP address if you want.
- "1521" is the port that the database is listening on.
- "orcl" is the name of the instance (or database service).

Comment: This may not work in all environments.  In my case it doesn't work with Oracle InstantClient 11g and Python 2.6 on 64-bit Windows 7.  The DSN method is more portable.

Comment: @Craig: thanks for the heads-up - can you tell me how it didn't work? What error is reported?

Comment: ORA-12514.  Basically the listener on `server` doesn't recognize `orcl` as an instance.  I couldn't make heads or tails of that, so I fired up a packet tracer, and the DSNs that are generated (for the Connect packet) are significantly different.  The server is Oracle 10g, which may be significant.

Comment: I re-ran my packet traces.  A connection made with `user/pass@host:port/dbname` ends up using `dbname` as the `SERVICE_NAME` instead of the `SID`, which fails for Oracle InstantClient 11g when talking to an Oracle 10g server.

Comment: I have the same problem, How did you suggest i connect using cx_oracle.

Answer (score 9):

```
import cx_Oracle

CONN_INFO = {
    'host': 'xxx.xx.xxx.x',
    'port': 12345,
    'user': 'user_name',
    'psw': 'your_password',
    'service': 'abc.xyz.com',
}

CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifying the SID, you can create a dsn and [connect via service_name](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.makedsn) like:

```
import cx_Oracle
ip = '192.168.0.1'
port = 1521
service_name = 'my_service'
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=service_name)

db = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'password', dsn)
```

The benefit of using the service name instead of the specific instance identifier (SID), is that it will work in a RAC environment as well (using a SID won't).  This parameter is available as of [cx_Oracle version 5.1.1](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/commits/b81bd10992eb6a4fb2a3e618cfdf865c72148859) (Aug 28, 2011)

Comment: @A.Raouf: See [here for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43901/429982)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import cx_Oracle
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='127.0.0.1', port=1521, sid='your_sid')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='your_username', password='your_password', dsn=dsn)
conn.close()
```

Comment: If your password have special symbols use this case!

Comment: How to make sure the connection is encrypted?

Answer (score -1):

```
import cx_Oracle
ip = '172.30.1.234'
port = 1524
SID = 'dev3'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('dbmylike', 'pass', dsn_tns)
print conn.version
conn.close()
```

Comment: This only works if the user has a SID, which was deprecated in favor of service_names years ago.  Other answers explain the difference. Update: other answers already show the syntax you gave.