# How can I access a clearquest oracle database from python?

Tags: python, oracle, clearquest

At work we have to use ClearQuest. Recently I have had the necessity of making some "complicated" queries and I have found that to be very difficult with the CQ query editor.

I have think about using python to connect directly to the database and make my own queries so I can run the script automagically, but I am unable to connect to the database.

I have follow the tip of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870849/156459

But without any success.

I have compared the cx_Oracle.makedsn return value with the one sent by the CQ client for windows and both are equal.

The error I get is "ORA-01017: Invalid username/password; logon denied" . I have double checked the user and password and are correct.

I have captured the TSN packets between the oracle server and my computer while running my script and I have seen something rare to me:  My computer ask for a connection and the server answer with Accept ...

Any help would be ( very ) welcomed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: are you sure the  oracle environment is set correctly and you the correct tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: I suppose ... I can connect to clearquest database without any problem using the cq windows client ...

Comment: what is the exact connect string? and how is the tns alias defined in the tnsnames.ora file?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your password contains any characters that require escaping.

[image: Escape Characters]