# ocx_Oracle ORA-12541 tns no listener

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I try to connect to a remote oracle server by cx_Oracle:

db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', dsn_tns)

but it says databaseError: ORA-12541 tns no listener

Answer (score 6):

I was able to connect via db client (e.g datagrip), but I got the No Listener error when i connect from python script because my original connection string did not specify the port. I was following the [cx_Oracle doc](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/)

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245465/cx-oracle-connecting-to-oracle-db-remotely) helped me by specifying the port this way:

```
ip = '192.168.0.1'
port = 1521
SID = 'YOURSIDHERE'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)

db = cx_Oracle.connect('username', 'password', dsn_tns)
```

Comment: thank you, that was really helpful. making a `dsn` in this way solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! `makedsn()` also accepts `service_name='foo'` instead of an SID, which is what I needed. https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/module.html#cx_Oracle.makedsn

Answer (score 2):

This error may occur if the listener.ora file (on the Oracle server itself) is configured to listen for "localhost" instead of the machine name.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***WN700014***)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

See [this post](http://www.mathewweaver.com/2013/08/listenerora-localhost.html).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to the fact that my server port was wrong:

> ./install_database_new.sh   localhost:1511 XE full

I changed the port to "1521" and I could connect.