# TimeOut error through connection oracle 10g with python - cx_Oracle remotely

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

Now I want to **connect to oracle database through vpn**, I already set up vpn configurations with *cli* and *programmatically* .

When I connect to the database using SqlAlchemy or cx_Oracle it gives me connection timeout occured

**Python == 2.7 

cx_Oracle == 6.01rc 

oracle == 10g 

os = linux ubuntu 16.04

oracle_instant_client = 12.2 Basic**

#### using cx_Oracle

```
ip = '<ip>'
port = 1521
service = '<dbname>'
sd = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service)
db = cx_Oracle.connect('<username>', '<pass>', sd)
```

`cx_Oracle` is 6.01rc and oracle version is 10g, it returns me

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

### First of all

What ip should I use, the ip that I already connected to in the vpn which is 41.22x.x.8 or the ip when `ifconfig` >> ppp0 >>> p-t-p:10.0.xx.21x ??

Where is the problem ? Is it authentication one or what, I don't understand why its timeout error
I think that `cx_Oracle` 6.01rc is not proper version to connect to oracle 10g so I tried cx_Oracle 5.3 but can't install

#### The VPN client is PPTP

[image: VPN is up]

#### Reference: [cx_Oracle & Connecting to Oracle DB Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245465/cx-oracle-connecting-to-oracle-db-remotely)

Comment: Can you tnsping the db, or connect through sqlplus?

Comment: Do u mean oracle instant client ?
it is oracle_instant_client = 12.2 Basic

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting through SQL*Plus. Once you can connect through SQL*Plus you should be able to connect through cx_Oracle, too. 5.3 and 6.0 should work the same way but if you want to try 5.3 you can download pre-built binaries from PyPI.

Comment: First Thanks,
Second I don't know how to connect using sql*plus only !! I don't have any exp in oracle and have to connect through a vpn at this case 
Do u mean that: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/connecting.htm#CEGIGEIJ ??

Comment: Yes, like that. You'll probably have an easier time figuring out how to connect through SQL*Plus -- and you can contact Oracle Support directly for it, if needed.

Comment: Thanks I contacted the provider of the service and it was his fault he didn't provide me which IP should I use :) Thanks