# Remote Oracle DB connection in python

Tags: database, oracle, python-db-api

I want to connect to remote oracle db using python.
Tried to using cx_Oracle.

Here is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle

adr = 'server_addres'
uid = 'user_id'
pwd = 'pwd'
port = 'port'

cx_Oracle.connect(uid + "/" + pwd + "@" + adr)
```

After execute, I am receiving error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

How to connect to my remote oracle db? Or maybe I should use something different than cx_Oracle?

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1870849/1917858

Comment: I already tried this resolution, but it isn't working for me. Still the same error.

Comment: Ok, i found the reason. In my db address i put '//' at the begging. Now, after deleted '//' it works. So stackoverflow.com/a/1870849/1917858 works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user="User_id", password="User_password", dsn="the_ip_address/XE", encoding="UTF-8")
print(conn.version)
conn.close()

It gave me output as
18.0.0.0.0 which is my oracle version