# Sqlplus default login and password?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I just installed `SQLPLUS` via this [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client). What are the default login and password credentials? Following the documentation, I already tried `sqlplus username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID` I have investigated similar questions below, but none of the solutions have been successful for me.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/159939/how-to-install-sqlplus#

[Oracle TNS: net service name is incorrecly specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237610/oracle-tns-net-service-name-is-incorrecly-specified)

[How come sqlplus not connecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761418/how-come-sqlplus-not-connecting/29423960#29423960)

I have tried `testuser`/`password` credentials

```
sqlplus64 username/password@//dbhost:1521/SID

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Oct 14 23:08:13 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name: testuser
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name:
```

**How do I login, I'm sorry the comments don't make sense to me, could someone please write out an example, should I be 1sqlpus 64 username/password@//dbhost:1521/` ?**

Comment: Use sqlplus instead sqlplus64 and Replace dbhost with ur server IP or server name, and SID with actual oracle_SID which u gave during installation (generally ORCL by default),  also there is no user with credentials testuser/password  u need to use which u created or try system/password which u gave during installation

Comment: So I should uninstall the 64 bit and go with the 32?

Comment: No need to unstall, it should work with sqlplus64 also

Comment: I'm running locally do I use `localhost` as my server?

Comment: Yes localhost can be used for dbhost

Comment: You know Ubuntu is not certified OS for Oracle database installation. better use Oracle Linux on VirtualBox, which is free for personal learning purpose.

Comment: As the error message indicates you should use service_name and not sid.

Comment: If you're connecting locally why are you trying to use ip:port? Just type .oraenv and then the SID. You can then just type sqlplus username/password  and it will log you in. Also ensure your listener is running (lsnrctl status).

Comment: How do I login, I'm sorry the comments don't make sense to me, could someone please write out an example, should I be `sqlpus 64 username/password@//dbhost:1521/` ?

Comment: You installed `SQL*Plus`.  Did you install an Oracle database earlier?  `SQL*Plus` is just a client.  You'd need to have a database to connect to.  If you had installed an Oracle database, it would be very odd to want to then install the Instant Client on the same machine.  So my guess is that you've installed the client, you have not installed the database, and you don't have a database for SQL*Plus to connect to.

Comment: @JustinCave your exactly right. Thank you. My oversight, I only installed the client