# Connecting to SQL server, getting error 2013 (HY000) Lost connection

Tags: database, linux, shell, sqlplus

I am on Linux, trying to connect to SQL server.

Using sqlplus, as below:

```
 sqlplus username/password@server:port;
```

Getting **ORA-12537** error - "TNS: Connection closed". This error comes after a long wait.

While trying to figure out what the issue was, I got -

- "TNSPING server:port" returned error : TNS-12537 TNS Connection closed.
- "TELNET server port" is working fine. It shows connected status.
- Also tried using Easy connect after reading another post [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761418/how-come-sqlplus-not-connecting). This is the command I tried "sqlplus username/password@//server/port". It gave me error ORA-12541 : TNS: No listener.

Just want to add that I am able to connect to an Oracle db using sqlplus, with no problem.
Version is 10.2.0.4.

Any idea how to fix this? Appreciate the help!

**UPDATE**: I did not know sqlplus can't connect to SQL server. I tried connecting using mysql, but got an error:

```
 MYSQL -h server -P port -u username -ppassword
```

returned error : ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error 104. This error also comes after a long wait.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can ***NOT*** use SQL*Plus to connect to SQL Server. It's an Oracle only tool.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that. Trying this for the first time. But I'm also not able to connect using **mysql**. Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Again: SQL*Plus is an Oracle only tool. It can only **only** connect to an Oracle database (and no, MySQL is not an Oracle database)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to connect to two different dbs. One is Oracle, the other SQL. As you mentioned, I'm not able to connect to SQL db using sqlplus. I get now why that was the case. But I am not able to connect to the SQL db using mysql. Have updated the question to try to make that clearer as well.

Comment: The `mysql` client program can **only** connect to a MySQL database. If you are looking for a more universal tool, you might want to look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/scriptable-command-line-access-to-sql-server-from-linux or this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567867/open-source-sql-client-viewer

Comment: Thanks for the links. We can't install anything new, so I'll try another way but will keep these in mind for future.

Comment: I can only speak about one of them: SQL Workben/J - it doesn't need any "installation". You just unzip the archive (it does need a Java runtime though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an SQL Server specific client to connect to SQL Server, sqlplus is a oracle client and mysql is a command line client for the mysql server. Microsoft provides a JDBC driver at http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx or a Linux ODBC driver at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28160. This might help if you have some kind of software that can use those drivers, e.g. RazorSQL (http://razorsql.com/features/sqlserver_features.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links! I will try using ODBC and post back the results.