# Getting the SID from Service Name

Tags: oracle, connection-string, sid

I am building a connection string for an Oracle DB. I have all the information I need except the SID. However, I DO have the Service Name of the DB. Is there any  way that I can retrieve the SID from the Service Name?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the service name in the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tnsping.exe utility may help you

Comment: The tnsping returns the Service Name. I just don't know if thats the same as the SID or if that is totally different.

Comment: Here is the explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866/how-sid-is-different-from-service-name-in-oracle-tnsnames-ora