# what differences SID and Service Name when use Oracle SQLDeveloper?

Tags: oracle, sid, service-name

English is not my native please understand

When I try to login like system/password as sysdba to oracle(linux) by sqldeveloper(window)

It fail when through Service Name and return ORA-0131 :insufficient privileges

but SID? successfully passed

what differences? and how to connect with Service Name?

Comment: No clue what you are asking.  Please show the commands you are trying to execute, etc.

Comment: `sysdba` role is not granted to the `system` account by default. When you specify `SID`(client and server on same computer) and connect as `sysdba` you will use OS authentication - oracle username and password will be ignored as long as OS user in in `DBA` group. When you use `service name` and connect as `sysdba` the password file will be used and if `sysdba` role is not granted to that user(user is not present in the password file), you'll get the `ORA-0131` error.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers

Answer (score 5):

Thomas Kyte explained the difference beatifully :

> A service name is more flexible than a SID would be.
>
> A database can dynamically register with a listener using one or more service names. In fact, more than one database can register with a listener using the same service name (think about a clustered environment where you have multiple instances that all are the same database under the covers).
>
> A database on the other hand has a single SID. And a single SID goes to a single database. It is a pure 1:1 relationship.
>
> A service is a many to many relationship.

Service names are used with dynamic registration - the data registers with the listener after it starts up. Once it does that, you can connect.

With the SID - that is more like telling the listener "I want you to connect to this specific database, I know the 'address', here you go"

With the SERVICE - you are asking the listener to put you in touch with a database that can service your request, a database that registers using that service.

More information here, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1508737000346067364

Similar question was asked in Stack Overflow 6 years back, [How SID is different from Service name in Oracle tnsnames.ora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866/how-sid-is-different-from-service-name-in-oracle-tnsnames-ora)

In your test environment, play around with `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora`. AFAIK, from 12c, Oracle uses only `service_name`, since it is flexible and has many to many relationship. I will cross-verify from documention if I find it incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @Glenn for the edit. Indeed it is ***many to many relationship in general***. But, as a conclusion, I said one to many specifically for OP's case.

Comment: wow Thanks @Lalit Kumar B But I don`t use tnsnames.ora and listener.ora I didn`t install Oracle Client

Comment: Regarding `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora`, it depends, whether you are conneting to the database locally or over the network.

Comment: Really? Isn`t it sqldeveloper uses jdbc??