# oracle connection string with SID in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, connection-string

Hi I have to connect to an Oracle Database( about which I know a little) using a windows application.
The windows application will not necessarily be in the same system.
I just needed the connection string.
So I Used Add connection functionality in Visual Studio 2014 to test the connection and get the string.
eedb is the SID which i read in [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866/how-sid-is-different-from-service-name-in-oracle-tnsnames-ora/)

[image]

Now using above, i was able to connect to the database using this functionality and even in my visual studio server explorer all the tables of the oracle database were showing but I needed to use the connection string in the windows application.
So I used following string:

```
DATA SOURCE=172.31.8.21:1521/eedb;USER ID=PDB_E_GND_R
```

I added password too to this string as

```
DATA SOURCE=172.31.8.21:1521/eedb;USER ID=PDB_E_GND_R;PASSWORD=123
```

when i run the application i get error.

```
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.
```

So :
Why I am getting this error. Now some may mark this question as duplicate and even point out the answer can be found in issue [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476875/ora-01017-invalid-username-password-when-connecting-to-11g-database-from-9i-clie)

Coz if this was the case I would have been unable to establish connection through add connection functionality of Visual Studio at all.
Please note: I added the reference: Oracle.DataAccess

And also for a programmer like me who has very little knowledge regarding the oracle.
How I can know which connection string I have to use for a particular oracle db.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following connection string EZ connect does not seem to be so EZ

data source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.31.8.21)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = eedb)));USER ID=PDB_E_GND_R;PASSWORD=123