# TNS-12518 > TNS-12560 >TNS-00530 > 64-bit Windows Error: 203: Unknown error

Tags: oracle, tns

*Hello everyone! I'd like to thank you in advance, for taking your time to look into this question, no matter if you have an answer or not. :)*

I already have the XE service running, but I can't get the ICIVM1D service to work. When trying to run my application, it fails with an error.

The log returns:

```
20-OKT-2017 10:40:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=skj))(SID=ICIVM1D)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.148.1)(PORT=53564)) * establish * ICIVM1D * 12518
TNS-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
   64-bit Windows Error: 203: Unknown error
```

I have unsuccesfully tried the solutions that were mentioned in questions regarding TNS-12518, TNS-12560 and TNS-00530, on stackoverflow and other websites.

The Oracle services are up and running, logged on as Local System (and host is localhost):

```
OracleServiceXE
OracleXETNSListener
```

The listener:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 20-OKT-2017 10:09:21

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                20-OKT-2017 08:36:03
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 33 min. 18 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   ..\listener.ora
Listener Log File         ..\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<my PC name>)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ICIVM1D" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ICIVM1D", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

listener.ora
(I see no difference in error, if I change the DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER and restart the listener.)

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = ICIVM1D)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <my PC name>)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tnsnames.ora

```
ICIVM1D =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ICIVM1D)
    )
  )

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

I've tried restarting the connection:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
Fixed Size                  2260048 bytes
Variable Size             666895280 bytes
Database Buffers          394264576 bytes
Redo Buffers                5517312 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

I've checked the number of processes:

```
SQL> show parameter processes

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
aq_tm_processes                      integer     0
db_writer_processes                  integer     1
gcs_server_processes                 integer     0
global_txn_processes                 integer     1
job_queue_processes                  integer     4
log_archive_max_processes            integer     4
processes                            integer     800
```

I've tried pinging:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tnsping icivm1d

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 20-OKT-2017 10:36:00

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = LOCALHOST)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ICIVM1D)))
OK (50 msec)
```

The alert return:

```
Create Relation ADR_CONTROL
```

Running SQL statements, I got the following results:

```
SQL> select name, value from v$PARAMETER where name like '%name%';

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lock_name_space


db_file_name_convert


log_file_name_convert



NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global_names
FALSE

instance_name
xe

service_names
XE


NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db_name
XE

db_unique_name
XE


8 rows selected.
```

And

```
SQL> select name, NETWORK_NAME from v$services;

NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------
NETWORK_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XEXDB
XEXDB

XE
XE

SYS$BACKGROUND



NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------
NETWORK_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS$USERS
```

Comment: Add line for localhost in listener.ora
   `LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <my PC name>)(PORT = 1521))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost )(PORT = 1521))
        )
      )`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DmitryDemin I added the localhost line and restarted the listener. The error log remains the same.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can only have 1 database instance running on XE. So if XE is already running there won't be an ICIVM1D.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Rene I removed the XE service from the listener.ora and the tnsnames.ora and restarted the listener and OracleServiceXe. Using the 'lsnrctl status' the XE is no longer mentioned as a service and ICIVM1D is mentioned as Default Service. However the error remains the same.

Comment: How did you make the ICIVM1D service from the OracleXE service? For ORACLE SID = ICIVM1D
you must create a second instance of the database with SID = ICIVM1D.
SID is an Oracle system identifier  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866/how-sid-is-different-from-service-name-in-oracle-tnsnames-ora

Comment: The tnsping utility is testing just that the listener accepts packets by IP address and by port 1521

Comment: Run this SQL select name, value from v$PARAMETER
where name like '%name%' and this select name, NETWORK_NAME from v$services

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look into this @DmitryDemin I already had the XE service up and running, using a local database, using SID XE. I then created a new database for ICIVM1D, using HOST=192.168.148.1 (the address of a virtual machine) and SID ICIVM1D. I added the information I thought appropriate to the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files, so it matched what was already there for the XE service. I then restarted the listener.

Comment: I ran your two SQL statements and will edit the OP with the results.

Comment: Sadly I will be offline untill monday morning, but then I will continue looking into it. And again, your effort is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You incorrectly made the ICIVM1D instance, you have only the XE instance of the express edition. Therefore, clients will not be able to connect to the ICIVM1D instance. it does not exist.

Comment: That makes sense. But I don't see where I went wrong in the process. Am I using the same network name for the ICIVM1D and therefore not able to create a service instance? And if that is the case, how do I go about changing that?